# Change the style of the two different html attributes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a question regarding the style in the iframe

the problem i have only access to the css file

I have lets say the following

```
<html>
<body>
...
<iframe src="abc" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

is there anyway I can change the width for the first html to 960px and the other to 100%
cause if I change the html attribute in the css it will affect both of them

I tried the `first-child` and `iframe html {}` but it didnt work

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please don't confuse elements and attributes. Also note that the end tag for the iframe element is mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A document loaded into an iframe is an independent document. CSS does not cascade through the iframe into it. You style the two pages independently with their own stylesheets.

Comment: In that case, this statement by the OP isn't correct? `cause if I change the html attribute in the css it will affect both of them`

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg — Only if the same stylesheet is loaded by both pages (and it means that `iframe html {}` is nonsense).